# Using Windows Firewall to block a specific IP on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, firewall, windows-firewall

For some reason I'm having some site pestering my LogMeIn account with a bad login. It is consistently the same IP. Rather than relying upon LogMeIn's rudimentary login security I'd rather entirely block that IP entirely. How do I do that using Windows Firewall?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security by running `wf.msc`. On the left, select Inbound Rules, then under the Action menu, choose New Rule.

- On the *Rule Type* page, choose Custom.
- On *Program*, choose "All programs."
- On *Protocol and Ports*, leave the default of Any.
- On *Scope*, select "These IP addresses" in the remote addresses section and add the problematic IP address in the Add dialog.
- On *Action*, choose "Block the connection."
- On *Profile*, leave the defaults of everything checked.
- Finally, on *Name*, give the rule a name and optionally a description.

Comment: where is protocol qnd ports?

Comment: @greenber It's one of the steps in the New Inbound Rule Wizard that appears once you select Custom on the first (Rule Type) page.

Comment: thank you!! between the both of you it works like a champ!

Answer (score 0):

I found the steps given in the correct answer work today, once again thanks. But not intuitive to follow in the Microsoft firewall wizard. Another more scaleable but still not intuitive way, is to use an elevated powershell console.

`New-NetFirewallRule -RemoteAddress 192.168.100.42 -DisplayName "Block Remote 100.42" -Direction inbound -Profile Any -Action Block`