# I have been port scanned repeatedly by an address in the Netherlands - I can only block by MAC address - how can I find it?

Tags: mac-address

I can only block inbound traffic by MAC address. 
How can I find the MAC address for a computer in the Netherlands. 
185.202.1.161 is the bad guy

Comment: Have you tried this solution which uses Windows Firewall? [Using Windows Firewall to block a specific IP on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1159401/using-windows-firewall-to-block-a-specific-ip-on-windows-10)

Comment: MAC addresses don't cross borders, so you cannot block the MAC address of a 'target' IP Address. I'm not actually sure how your router thinks it can even do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It would be reaching you via a host (which is likely your default gateway) in your LAN and you can only block the MAC Address of that (which will likely end up blocking everything from the Internet). Even if you can "trace" its MAC by some means adding it to your firewall rule won't help.